# SyncFusion Drag and Drop Angular Tabs

Tags: javascript, angular, syncfusion

I'm trying to get the Angular Drag and Drop tabs working with the SyncFusion component library. I have tried everything I can from [the documentation](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/tab/drag-and-drop/) but they still don't reorder.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="tab-container">
  <div class="col-lg-8 content-wrapper control-section">
    <ejs-tab id='draggableTab' #tabObj [allowDragAndDrop]='allowDragAndDrop' dragArea='#tab-container'
         (created)='onTabCreate()' (onDragStart)='onTabDragStart($event)' (dragged)='onDraggedTab($event)'>
      <e-tabitems>
        <e-tabitem *ngFor="let item of headerText" [header]="item" [content]="contentTemplate"></e-tabitem>
      </e-tabitems>
    </ejs-tab>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here are the relevant parts of the TypeScript file:

```
onTabCreate(): void {
  const tabElement = document.getElementById("#draggableTab");
  if (!isNullOrUndefined(tabElement)) {
    tabElement.querySelector(".e-tab-header").classList.add("e-droppable");
    tabElement.querySelector(".e-content").classList.add("tab-content");
  }
}
onTabDragStart(args: DragEventArgs): void {
  this.draggedItemHeader = <string> this.tabObj.items[args.index].header.text;
}
onDraggedTab(args: DragEventArgs): void {
  const dragTabIndex: number = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.tabObj.element.querySelectorAll(".e-toolbar-item"), args.draggedItem);
  const dropContainer: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement> args.target.closest("#TabContainer .content-wrapper .e-toolbar-item");
  const dropNode: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement> args.target.closest("#TabContainer .content-wrapper .e-toolbar-item");
  if (dropNode != null) {
    args.cancel = true;
    const dropIndex: number = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(dropContainer, dropNode);
    console.log(dropIndex);
  }
}
```

In the `onDraggedTab` method I am trying to get the index of where to place the tab, but can't figure it out. The `dropNode` is valid, and defined, but getting its index to swap it with the `target` (or the dragged tab) is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dropped item index in dragged event using below customization. We have prepared a sample in which we have logged the dropped item index in the console which can be referred through the below link.

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tab-drag-and-drop?file=app.component.ts

```
  public onDraggedTab(args: DragEventArgs): void {

    const dragTabIndex: number = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(

      this.tabObj.element.querySelectorAll('.e-toolbar-item'),

      args.draggedItem

    );

    const dropItem: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>(

      args.target.closest('#draggableTab .e-toolbar-item')

    );

    if (dropItem != null) {

      //args.cancel = true;

      let dropItemContainer: Element = args.target.closest('.e-toolbar-items');

      const dropIndex: number =

        dropItemContainer != null

          ? Array.prototype.slice

              .call(dropItemContainer.querySelectorAll('.e-toolbar-item'))

              .indexOf(dropItem)

          : '';

      console.log(dropIndex);

    }

  }
```